# Grid View Out of Range Exception, Value in Range

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a GridView:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="_gv_AllResp" Width="100%"  style="color: White;" DataKeyNames="recordid" 
    Font-Size="10pt" OnDataBound="_gvDataBind_Eve"  AutoGenerateSelectButton="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="_gv_AllResp_SelectedIndexChanged">
      <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
      <HeaderStyle BackColor="#57768f"/>
      <RowStyle BackColor="#dae2e8" ForeColor="Black" />
      <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#ffffff" ForeColor="Black" />
</asp:GridView>
```

That I bind from the code behindwith ADO:

```
SELECT a.[recordid], [lname] + ', ' + [fname] as [name], Convert(char, [datebirth],   101)  as 'DOB', phone1, phone2, phone3, ext FROM [dbo].[Respondent] a
```

I then have a procedure to select a random number of records from the grid and insertthem into a table:

```
var rnd = new Random();
        var _rand = Enumerable.Range(0, _RowCount).Select(x => new { val = x, order =  rnd.Next() }).OrderBy(i => i.order).Select(x => x.val).Take(_LockCount).ToArray();

        string _jobnum = _dd_ActJobs.SelectedValue.ToString();

        foreach (var a in _rand)
        {
            int b = Convert.ToInt32(a);
            using (var con = new SqlConnection())
            {
                con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RM_V1.0CS"].ConnectionString;
                try
                {
                    con.Open();

                    var cmd = new SqlCommand("INS_DemoLockQuery", con) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure };
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@jobnum", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100, "jobnum");
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@respnum", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100, "respnum");
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100, "name");
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@phone", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100, "phone");
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@wphone", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100, "wphone");
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@wphone_ext", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100, "wphone_ext");
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@cellphone", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100, "cellphone");
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@quota", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100, "quota");

                    cmd.Parameters["@jobnum"].Value = _jobnum;
                    //GETTING ERROR HERE 
                    cmd.Parameters["@respnum"].Value = _gv_AllResp.Rows[b].Cells[1].Text.ToString();
                    cmd.Parameters["@name"].Value = _gv_AllResp.Rows[b].Cells[2].Text.ToString();
                    cmd.Parameters["@phone"].Value = _gv_AllResp.Rows[b].Cells[4].Text.ToString().Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "").Replace("-", "").Replace(" ", "").Trim();
                    cmd.Parameters["@wphone"].Value = _gv_AllResp.Rows[b].Cells[5].Text.ToString().Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "").Replace("-", "").Replace(" ", "").Trim();
                    cmd.Parameters["@wphone_ext"].Value = _gv_AllResp.Rows[b].Cells[6].Text.ToString().Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "").Replace("-", "").Replace(" ", "").Trim();
                    cmd.Parameters["@cellphone"].Value = _gv_AllResp.Rows[b].Cells[7].Text.ToString().Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "").Replace("-", "").Replace(" ", "").Trim();
                    cmd.Parameters["@quota"].Value = _ddActQuota.SelectedValue.ToString();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    ViewAvailable();
                }
                //catch (Exception ex) { ErrHandler.WriteError(ex.Message); }
                finally { con.Close(); }
            }
        }
```

I'm getting the following "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index" There are 145 rows in the grid and the value of b (row number) is 120 for instance for this particular test.  This is in the range of allowable rows.  I'm don't understand how this is outside the index range.

Stack Trace

```
   at System.Collections.ArrayList.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at Default3._b_selectRepond(Object sender, EventArgs e) in   c:\Afocus\Jobs\Query.aspx.cs:line 668
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   at     System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(Str     ing eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean  includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Any Suggestions ? Thanks in advance Guys / Girls

### EDIT @ James

I just tried using the datakeynames as you suggested and replaced the insert block with

```
                    cmd.Parameters["@jobnum"].Value = _jobnum;
                    cmd.Parameters["@respnum"].Value = _gv_AllResp.DataKeys[b]["recordid"].ToString();
                    cmd.Parameters["@name"].Value = _gv_AllResp.DataKeys[b]["Name"].ToString().Replace("&nbsp;", "");
                    cmd.Parameters["@phone"].Value = _gv_AllResp.DataKeys[b]["Main"].ToString().Replace("&nbsp;", "").Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "").Replace("-", "").Replace(" ", "").Trim();
                    cmd.Parameters["@wphone"].Value = _gv_AllResp.DataKeys[b]["Work Phone"].ToString().Replace("&nbsp;", "").Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "").Replace("-", "").Replace(" ", "").Trim();
                    cmd.Parameters["@wphone_ext"].Value = _gv_AllResp.DataKeys[b]["ext"].ToString().Replace("&nbsp;", "").Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "").Replace("-", "").Replace(" ", "").Trim();
                    cmd.Parameters["@cellphone"].Value = _gv_AllResp.DataKeys[b]["Cell Phone"].ToString().Replace("&nbsp;", "").Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "").Replace("-", "").Replace(" ", "").Trim();
                    cmd.Parameters["@quota"].Value = _ddActQuota.SelectedValue;
```

However I still get the same error,  I tried to "lock" 50 records with 145 rows in the grid and it looped through 23 times and then threw an error n the 135 row (b=135) Same Error "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index"

Comment: Is the code shown above, the code at or near line 668 of query.aspx.cs?

Comment: When do you call this random selection method? Is the grid filled out when the random selections are made?

Comment: Yeah there a whole set of criteria that must be met prior to selection.  Selection lock count >= row count, rowcount > 0 etc... But the out of range exceptions all occur on rows that exist that's what's throwing me.

Comment: post code for selectRepond() method.  And fix the method typo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're specifying the column indexes starting at position `1` instead of `0`. You have 7 columns in your select, so your column indexes should range `0-6`.

I believe this is the offending line:

```
 _gv_AllResp.Rows[b].Cells[7].Text // = bang!
```

**EDIT**

To eliminate the problem altogether, use data keys to access the columns you need:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Name, DOB, phone1, phone2, ..." >
```

And in the code-behind:

```
string name = GridView1.DataKeys[0]["Name"].ToString();
```

Comment: Edited my answer with a solution that should eliminate the issue altogether.

Comment: You're using the row index to retrieve the data keys, right? `GridView1.DataKeys[rowIndex]["Name"].ToString();`

Comment: Well b is a range value between the min and max of the row index yes ... I assume thats what you mean