# argument out of range exception was unhandled by the user

Tags: c#

the following code generate the error the above error while clicking on the edit button.

```
protected void uxStaffGrid_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.CommandName == "Select")

    {
        //Determine the RowIndex of the Row whose Button was clicked.

        int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

        //Reference the GridView Row.

        GridViewRow row = uxStaffGrid.Rows[rowIndex];

        //Fetch value of Name.

        //  string name = (row.FindControl("txtId") as Label).Text;


        string Id = row.Cells[1].Text;
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ConsumeID", "ConsumeID('" + Id + "');", true);

    }
}
```

the error occured on line:

```
GridViewRow row = uxStaffGrid.Rows[rowIndex]
```

Comment: Debug and check `uxStaffGrid.Rows[rowIndex];` either `row.Cells[1].Text;` lines.

Comment: @SᴇM `row.Cells[1]` might also trigger this exception

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7718026/10466324 please review this post.

Comment: @IMil I have that line in the second part of my comment.

Comment: @SᴇM sorry didn't notice :)

Comment: I'd put my money on the row.Cells[1] being the problem, since rowIndex is provided by the command argument. Perhaps it should be row.Cells[0]? Total guess...

Comment: BTW, the error message will tell you which line it occurred on!

Comment: you can try remove the last row of the datagridview like `allowuserstoaddrow=false` in the properties

Comment: the error occured on line GridViewRow row = uxStaffGrid.Rows[rowIndex];

Comment: i tried row.Cells[1].Text but not working.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a control class instead of their types:

```
GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
```

Comment: try this GridViewRow selectedRow = (GridViewRow)(((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);